# Python 3 How can i take multi digit input and break into each digit

Tags: python, input

I want to be able to have the user enter a number of multiple digits and be able to take the input apart so I can operate on the individual digits.
I can do it for 2 digits and I guess I could write a loop to take digits out automatically.
Once I have each digit I want to square and sum and repeat until the squares sum to 1 or converge to value other than 1.

Again I can do for 2 digits without loop but need to repeat until 1 or not.

Ex. Input 23
2^2 + 3^2=13
Then take 1^2 + 3^3=9
9 is end

I don't want the actual code but 
1. best way to take input apart to store and operate on it
2. Best loop type to reach 1 or not. 
It's an exercise called happy numbers which I'm sure I could find but I'm teaching myself python (I know F77 and Perl-which as python users know it's the anti Perl...lol). Its been while since coding anything so I've learned basics of python and ruby and since python like Fortran seems integrated into science I'm focused on that. I learned Perl for bioinformatics grad classes but python would have worked. Any help is appreciated. Also any advice if I'm right going python instead of ruby for my needs appreciated.

Comment: showing that you tried something would be great..seems you have the idea in mind so try it out

Comment: Both python and ruby are great scripting languages .  I prefer python but that's my opinion

Answer (score 1):

Some corrections may be required in the example. For instance

> 23 -> 2^2 + 3^2 = 13 -> 1^2 + 3^2 = 10 -> 1^2 = 1.

1. If you like to refer to the digits of the number you should convert it to string or to list of the digits (as integer numbers on interval [0, 9]).

   - The string convertion is straightforward with `str` function, for example `str(23)`.
   - For the list of digits you can use list comprehension as `[int(d) for d in str(number)]`.
2. In this type of iteration you did not know the number of steps in advance which means the `while` loop is appropriate in this situation.

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to split out the digits:

1. Arithmetic: Integer division by 10 will give you the last digit as the remainder, and the rest of the digits as the quotient. In Python the best way would be with `divmod()`:

   ```
   >>> rest, last = divmod(2017, 10)
   >>> print(rest, last)
   201 7
   ```
2. As a string of digits: Convert the number into its printed form and play with the digits.

   ```
   >>> digits = list(str(2017))
   >>> digits
   ['2', '0', '1', '7']
   ```

   You can convert the digit characters back to integers with, e.g., `int(digits[0])`.

So there's the answer to your question. Have fun manipulating the digits.